# RestSharp - Deserializing complex objects

Tags: c#, .net, rest, deserialization, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to harvest data from an API of one of the commercial products we're using at work. I'm having some trouble deserializing some of the more "complex" objects that are being returned.

Let me show you one of the cases I'm having trouble with. Have a look at the following example XML:

```
<RESTAPI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="API.xsd">
    <ActionResults Resource="../api/action/1854/status">
        <ActionID>1854</ActionID>
        <Status>Open</Status>
        <DateIssued>Tue, 03 Feb 2015 08:24:14 +0000</DateIssued>
        <Computer ID="68787" Name="PO141303026">
            <Status>The action executed successfully.</Status>
            <State IsError="0">3</State>
            <ApplyCount>1</ApplyCount>
            <RetryCount>1</RetryCount>
            <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
            <StartTime>Tue, 03 Feb 2015 08:39:41 +0000</StartTime>
            <EndTime>Tue, 03 Feb 2015 08:40:42 +0000</EndTime>
        </Computer>
        <Computer ID="5050237" Name="PO141303021">
            <Status>The action executed successfully.</Status>
            <State IsError="0">3</State>
            <ApplyCount>1</ApplyCount>
            <RetryCount>1</RetryCount>
            <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
            <StartTime>Tue, 03 Feb 2015 09:37:25 +0000</StartTime>
            <EndTime>Tue, 03 Feb 2015 09:38:14 +0000</EndTime>
        </Computer>
        <Computer ID="5520173" Name="PO141303017">
            <Status>The action executed successfully.</Status>
            <State IsError="0">3</State>
            <ApplyCount>1</ApplyCount>
            <RetryCount>1</RetryCount>
            <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
            <StartTime>Tue, 03 Feb 2015 16:27:31 +0000</StartTime>
            <EndTime>Tue, 03 Feb 2015 16:28:11 +0000</EndTime>
       </Computer>
    </ActionResults>
</BESAPI>
```

I tried representing this with following classes:

```
class ActionResults
{
    public ActionDetail()
    {
        // Empty constructor for RestSharp
    }

    public int ActionID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateIssued { get; set; }
    public List<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
}

class Computer
{
    public Computer()
    {
        // Empty constructor for RestSharp
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
    public int ApplyCount { get; set; }
    public int RetryCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

The top-level elements of ActionResult are filled up without problem, but the list of results per Computer are never filled up.

I tried changing the names of the classes and properties to match up exactly as is required in the [documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization#xmldeserializer-1).

Furthermore I tried using the DeserializeAs attribute as described in the link above as well, but it seems like the attribute is completely ignored.

Then I tried implementing a custom deserializer, but this is tricky as well. See, I'm using the recommended usage suggested over [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage), especially the Execute method. I wanted to keep said method as generic as possible.

Unfortunately you can only add handlers for deserializing certain content types, not for specific data models.

What would be the correct set of C# classes to deserialize the XML above? If this is not possible, what is the best solution for keeping the solution as generic as possible?

Comment: I would guess that the problem is related to the fact that there is no <Computers> element surrounding the list of <Computer> elements.  Not sure if there is any way that an automatic deserializer can deal with that.  Personally, I would just write the code to manually convert the XML into the objects.

Comment: @Darrel Hmm, I thought https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization#xmldeserializer-2 explicitly stated that it was not necessary for these elements to be wrapped into a collection in the XML.

Comment: Ahh.  I did not know that. I didn't realize that John had implemented his own serializer in RestSharp

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same problem